# Three.js Floating curve is merged into CubeGeometry

Tags: three.js

Please look at this 3D scene: (the link became obsolete)

The curve is made of multiple (1092) short THREE.Line objects.
 This curve, the ball (THREE.SphereGeometry) and the sod (THREE.CubeGeometry) are nested in THREE.Object3D which I am rotating using rotation.x and rotation.y properties.

The problem is that the curve sometimes is merged into the sod or visible through an opposite side of it although the curve actually "hangs" above the sod.

Comment: Please provide your code, or better yet, a live link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is an artifact of `CanvasRenderer`. The best you can do is tessellate your geometry. For example,

```
THREE.CubeGeometry( 50, 3, 50, 4, 1, 4 );
```

three.js r.58

Comment: The cube disappeared! (it became white). Btw.: what is `three.js r.58` ?

Comment: Oh, I understood: tesselation requires more colors in `geometry.faces[i].color` (for your example - 47 instead of previous 6). Thank you. The curve still merges into cube, but isn't visible through it. The cube looks now tiled. How to join tiles without gaps?

Comment: Please accept this answer, and if you have more issues, please make a new post with sufficient information to help you. r.58 is the three.js version number.